# Getting a of min. values from a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dictionary

Specifics:

I'm using a dictionary as such:

```
Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, Node>>;
```

To simplify things, let's say the Node contains an int value.

From this, I want to sort this by Item1 of the tuple in ascending order and then sort the ties (i.e. the values are the same) by the value contained in the Node object, such that the lowest value in both value and node value is first after sorting.

```
var sumList = from pair in openList
        orderby pair.Value.Item1 ascending
        select pair;
```

I've done the first part. How can I change this so I can apply the second part as well?

Example:

```
Node nod1 = new Node(1);
Node nod2 = new Node(2);
Node nod3 = new Node(3);
Node nod4 = new Node(4);

Dictionary.Add(3, nod1);
Dictionary.Add(3, nod4);
Dictionary.Add(2, nod2);
Dictionary.Add(2, nod3);

//result after sort
nod2
nod3
nod1
nod4
```

Comment: What propery of the Node class are you sorting on?

Comment: some int that's contained in the node.

Comment: cool, should be easy then. if it was some custom type, you'd need to make sure it implemented IComparable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would think this would be easier to achieve by expressions, running with it as an `IQueryable<KeyValuePair<int, Node>>` would allow you to do something like this:

```
openList.OrderBy(c => c.Value.Item1)
    .ThenBy(c => c.Value.Item2.NodeValuePropToSortOn)
```

but if you need to use the query syntax, you can do something like this:

```
var sumList = from pair in openList
    orderby pair.Value.Item1 ascending, pair.Value.Item2.NodeValuePropToSortOn ascending
    select pair;
```

multiple `orderby` properties are chained into `OrderBy`, `ThenBy`.

Comment: there is absolutely nothing gained by IQueryable expressions

Comment: Nothing is gained, however the syntax can or cannot be clearer - depending on what you are doing - it is opinion based - and in reality when you say `orderby` in query expression, it is doing the exact same thing as when you are saying `.OrderBy(c => c.Key)` - it is mapping the IL to do a `call instance` to the method `Enumerable.OrderBy` or `Queryable.OrderBy` or ThenBy, depending.

Comment: your query syntax ended up working for me! Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ThenBy`...

```
var sumLists = openList
    .OrderBy(pair => pair.Value.Item1)
    .ThenBy(pair => pair.Value.Item2.NodeProperty);
```